# UIImageView setImage not working on iPad while working fine on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiimage

I started with a Universal app project but have changed it to iPhone only everything works fine in iPad (both pixel doubling mode and 1x mode) except for the following line

in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

......

        UIImageView* iview = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:405];
    [iview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"searchlist_%@Thumb", c.Name]]];    

}
```

the image simply doesn't show up, what could be different on iPad?

the cell is pre configured in nib and is being loaded properly and other labels are being set properly

I'm also getting these assertions in console

Assertion failed: (cls), function getName, file /SourceCache/objc4_Sim/objc4-427.1.1/runtime/objc-runtime-new.m, line 3939.

Comment: Your title contradicts the first line of your question. For which does it work, iPhone or iPad? If it's no longer Universal, for which device is it targeted?

Comment: works fine on iPhone, the app other than this code works fine on iPad as well but on iPad its running as iPhone app with pixel doubling and/or 1x mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be caused by any number of things. First, reformat your code so it looks like this:

```
UIImageView* iview = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:405];
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"searchlist_%@Thumb", c.Name];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName] 
[iview setImage:image];
```

Then set a breakpoint on the last line. In the debugger you can check the values of `iview`, `imageName`, and `image`. Which one of those has an unexpected value will give you a clue where to look for the source of the problem.

Comment: image is 0x0 so iPad is unable to find image?

Comment: Yep. Now compare `imageName` with the files in the app bundle to see if its actually there. Maybe the image files weren't added to a new Xcode build target?

Comment: I've only one build target and GetInfo shows the file selected for that target

Comment: and the file is present in the bundle when I look it up in finder under Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.2/Applications

Comment: ok solved it. I had to add .png at file name wonder why it would work in iPhone simulator and not in iPad?

Comment: According to the documentation for imageNamed: "On iOS 4 and later, the name of the file is not required to specify the filename extension. Prior to iOS 4, you must specify the filename extension." Is the iPad running iOS 3.2? Or are you targeting iOS 3.2?

Comment: yes the simulator was running on 3.2 and I would target 3.2 so that explains it